# Char size in .net is not as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, char

size of char is : 2  ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

```
sizeof(char)  //2
```

a test :

```
char[] c = new char[1] {'a'};

Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(c) //1 ?
```

why the value is  1?

*(of course if c is a unicode char like 'ש' so it does show 2 as it should.)*

`a` is not .net char ?

Comment: UTF-8 is a _variable byte_ Unicode encoding.

Comment: @Oded: Then `char c = 'é';` is fine on C#.NET?

Comment: @TheMask - Yes, it is, so long as the `.cs` file is Unicode.

Comment: Douglas,Oded: Thanks very much.

Comment: @Royi - Unicode is a specification. UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and other Unicode encodings are _implementations_. The specification doesn't say how many bytes a character should be or how they are to be encoded.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: “Unicode” can be implemented by different character encodings, the most popular being UTF-8 and UTF-16. Unfortunately, .NET may give rise to confusion since it uses the term “Unicode” to refer to UTF-16 in particular.

Comment: @Douglas - Good point about `Encoding.Unicode`. Not the best name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because 'a' only takes one byte to encode in UTF-8.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(c)` will tell you how many bytes it takes to encode the given array of characters in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). See the documentation for [`Encoding.GetByteCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytecount.aspx) for more details. That's entirely separate from how wide the `char` type is internally in .NET.

Each character with code points less than 128 (i.e. U+0000 to U+007F) takes a single byte to encode in UTF-8.

Other characters take 2, 3 or even 4 bytes in UTF-8. (There are values over U+1FFFF which *would* take 5 or 6 bytes to encode, but they're not part of Unicode at the moment, and probably never will be.)

Note that the only characters which take 4 bytes to encode in UTF-8 can't be encoded in a single `char` anyway. A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, and any Unicode code points over U+FFFF require two UTF-16 code units forming a *surrogate pair* to represent them.

Comment: GetByteCode ? did you mean GetByteCount ?

Comment: @Royi - typo for GetByteCount(c) I expect

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that, internally, .NET represents characters as UTF-16, where each character typically occupies 2 bytes. On the other hand, in UTF-8, each character occupies 1 byte if it’s among the first 128 codepoints (which incidentally overlap with ASCII), and 2 or more bytes beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

That's not fair. The page you mention says

> The char keyword is used to declare a Unicode character

Try then:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(c)
```